# Singleton subset of Hausdorff set $S$ with discrete topology $\mathcal T$

Tags: general-topology

Let $S$ be a Hausdorff space with discrete topology $\mathcal T$ and $\{x\} \subset S$ a singleton subset. Because $S$ is endowed with the discrete topology, $\{x\}$ is *open*. However, since $S$ is Hausdorff it can be shown that $\{x\}$ is *closed* since $S - \{x\}$ is open.

Does this mean that in this particular case (Hausdorff and discrete topology) the singleton set is both open and closed?

Comment: Yes. Which step of the proof are you unsure about?

Comment: I think it just caught me a bit off guard, even though I couldn't find anything wrong with the proof. Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A discrete space is already Hausdorff. So it is superfluous to use Hausdorff with discrete space.

$\forall x\in X, \{x\}$ open implies $A=\cup_{a\in A}\{a\}$ is open. Hence every subset of $X$ is open.

Every $A\subset X$ is also closed as $X\setminus A$ is open.

Note: Discrete space is the only exception where each sigleton subsets are open.

Comment: Yes, it is but the singleton being both open and closed I just found a bit unexpected.

Comment: Well. Discrete space the only exception where each singleton set is open.

Comment: @FridoRolloos. Every subset of a discrete space is open and closed.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet ah yes of course. Succinct way to put it. Sorry for the basic question folks, still getting used to abstract / general concepts of open and closed